# AWS Amplify GraphQL filter by dynamic Cognito User Group

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

Given the following AWS Amplify GraphQL Schema (`schema.graphql`):

```
type Organization
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: groups, groups: ["Full-Access-Admin"], mutations: [create, update, delete], queries: [list, get] },
    { allow: owner },
    { allow: groups, groupsField: "orgAdminsCognitoGroup", mutations: null, queries: [list, get] }
  ]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    address: String!
    industry: [String]!
    owner: String
    orgAdminsCognitoGroup: String
  }
```

I can filter out all organizations except the ones that belong to the current authenticated user via the following:

```
        res = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listOrganizations, {
            // todo: filter by owner OR by is org admin
            filter: {
                owner: {
                    eq: this.props.currentUser.username
                }
            }
        }));
```

but is there anyway to also filter by the `orgAdminsCognitGroup` which is a dynamic group in Cognito belonging to the organization? I have not found any success trying to use an additional `@model` to help with the `@auth` rules to protect each entity.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the question? I'm not quite sure I understand. Are you trying to find the orgs to which groups the currently signed in user have access to? Or are you simply trying to filter over a specific group, singular?

Comment: I am trying to query for all organizations that this user has access to, and then I want to filter those results such that the only organizations returned are the ones that I am an owner of, or also part of that organization as an admin. In other words, all of the organizations that are returned to me because of the `Full-Access-Admin` group, I want to filter those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the question is wanting to filter groups that the user is either the owner of, or in the 'orgAdminsCognitoGroup'?

I think it's possible, though I don't think the best way is what you had in mind. Instead, I might recommend you set up a response mapping template that does some server side filtering for you.

Specifically, you would first get the groups from the current user's auth token:

```
#set($claimPermissions = $ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:groups"))
```

Then you could iterate over every organization in the results. If any have an owner that is the current user, add them to a response list. If they aren't, continue to check the orgAdminsCognitoGroup. You'd do that by checking whether or not $claimPermissions contains the group that the orgAdmin is set to for that organization. If it is contained, add it to the response list. If not, ignore it and continue iterating.

It would be possible, theoretically, to do this client side with the token the user has signed in with. Much in the same way the response mapping template did it, the groups the user is in are inside the token. If you crack it open and pull out the groups, you could apply the filtering there. I would recommend not doing this for security reasons, though it is possible.

Comment: Hmm, okay this was something that I was a bit worried about. Because I don't know how to create my own resolvers yet so I'm not sure where to place this code. Could you recommend any resources or point me in the right direction?

Comment: For sure, VTL in resolvers can be tricky. First of all, two alternatives if you don't want to spend a ton of effort on getting resolvers working: my last paragraph above, and using a Lambda resolver instead. A Lambda resolver would open you up to handling the post processing in a language of your choice, and would still provide the benefits of server side filtering. It would hypothetically call whatever your data store is first, then filter the results based on owner and groups (having cracked open the token), then return those  results. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you decide you do want to go with the resolver idea, there's a few samples built into the console that could help serve as inspiration. If you go to the resolver page, you'll see a dropdown on the right side of the two templates that say 'select a sample template'. Under request, you'll see 'Cognito User Pool Group Access'. This has multiple of the pieces you'd need, though again, I'd recommend it be in the response. Similarly, in response, there's 'return only if viewable from my groups'.